# kubectl log shows 'standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"'

Tags: docker, events, knative

I am trying to create a containerSource for knative service. When I use docker run for the image it gives the output ("or the error from the code"). However when I apply the yaml file then kubectl log shows 'standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"'. docker run shows that it is able to find the exec file. So I am not able to understand whats wrong. Someone please guide me through.

my yaml file:

```
apiVersion: sources.eventing.knative.dev/v1alpha1
kind: ContainerSource
metadata:
  labels:
    controller-tools.k8s.io: "1.0"
  name: cloudevents-source
spec:
  image: docker.io/username/pkt-event:latest
  args:
   - '--debug=true'
  sink:
    apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1alpha1
    kind: Service
    name: event-display
```

my go code for the dockerimage is:

```
package main

import (
        "context"
        "flag"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os"
        "time"
        "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
        "knative.dev/eventing-contrib/pkg/kncloudevents"
        "encoding/json"
//      "io/ioutil"
//      "knative.dev/eventing-contrib/vendor/github.com/cloudevents/sdk-go/pkg/cloudevents"
        "github.com/cloudevents/sdk-go/pkg/cloudevents"
        "github.com/cloudevents/sdk-go/pkg/cloudevents/types"
        "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"
)


var (
        eventSource string
        eventType   string
        sink        string
)
//var u, _ =  uuid.NewV4()

var debug = flag.Bool("debug", false, "Enable debug mode (print more information)")
var source = flag.String("source", uuid.NewV4().String(), "Set custom Source for the driver")

func init() {
        flag.StringVar(&eventSource, "eventSource", "", "the event-source (CloudEvents)")
        flag.StringVar(&eventType, "eventType", "dev.knative.eventing.samples.pkt", "the event-type (CloudEvents)")
        flag.StringVar(&sink, "sink", "", "the host url to send pkts to")
}

type envConfig struct {
        // Sink URL where to send heartbeat cloudevents
        Sink string `envconfig:"SINK"`
}

func main() {
        flag.Parse()

        var env envConfig
        if err := envconfig.Process("", &env); err != nil {
                log.Printf("[ERROR] Failed to process env var: %s", err)
                os.Exit(1)
        }

        if env.Sink != "" {
                sink = env.Sink
        }

        if eventSource == "" {
                eventSource = fmt.Sprintf("https://knative.dev/eventing-contrib/cmd/heartbeats/#local/demo")
                log.Printf("Source: %s", eventSource)
        }
        client, err := kncloudevents.NewDefaultClient(sink)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("failed to create client: %s", err.Error())
        }
        var period time.Duration
        period = time.Duration(1) * time.Second

        ticker := time.NewTicker(period)
        for {
                content := "Send data"
                data, err := json.Marshal(content)
                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Println(err)
                }
                event := cloudevents.Event{
                        Context: cloudevents.EventContextV02{
                                Type:   "packet.invoke",
                                Source: *types.ParseURLRef(eventSource),
                                /*Extensions: map[string]interface{}{
                                        "the":   42,
                                        "heart": "yes",
                                        "beats": true,
                                },*/
                        }.AsV02(),
                        Data: data,
                }
                if *debug{
                        log.Printf("Sending event %v", event)
                } else {
                        if _, err := client.Send(context.TODO(), event); err != nil {
                                log.Printf("failed to send cloudevent: %s", err.Error())
                        }
                }

                <-ticker.C
        }
}
```

And Dockerfile is:

```
FROM golang:1.12 as builder
RUN go version

WORKDIR ${GOPATH}/src/Event-driver

COPY ./ ./

RUN  curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
##RUN dep ensure

RUN dep init
RUN dep ensure

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -v -o my-event my-event.go

RUN pwd && ls

FROM scratch
#FROM ubuntu:disco
COPY --from=builder /go/src/Event-driver/my-event /


ENTRYPOINT ["/my-event"]
```

Answer (score 0):

That problem occurs because you're trying to run your binary from bash, but scratch has no bash.

I'm normally using alpina instead. To build for alpina you need the same environment variables, so probably you only need to change a second stage image.

Comment: Hi llya Kaznacheev, I tried alpine as well as ubuntu:disco but error is always same. exec user process caused "no such file or directory". Infact my docker run ti <image> runs properly its just when I apply yaml file it fails.

Comment: Interestingly when I changed my yaml file to image myevent instead of pkt-event it works. However I used same Dockerfile and code. Is there any reason why pkt-event was creating a problem?